# Cannot call message.topic in a MQTT client?

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I have this problem, where my `on_message` method will stop working correctly, when I call `msg.topic`. I do not get an error, but the print statements do not execute anymore, although new messages are being sent.

What is the problem?

```
import paho.mqtt.client as client

hostname = 'iot.eclipse.org'
topic = 'Mein/Topic'

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    msg = msg.payload.decode()
    print("topic:", msg.topic)
    print("Received Message:      {}".format(msg))

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connection returned result: " + str(rc) +
          "\n")
    if rc == 0:
        print("Listening now.\n")
    client.subscribe(topic)

client = client.Client()
client.on_message = on_message
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.connect(hostname)
client.loop_forever()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paho client has a built in try/expect block that wraps the call to `on_message` to prevent badly behaving callbacks from crashing the network thread.

If you want to know where your code is failing you can add your own try/expect to the inside of the `on_message` function to show the problem. Something like:

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    try:
        msg = msg.payload.decode()
        print("topic:", msg.topic)
        print("Received Message:      {}".format(msg))
    expect Exception, e:
        print(e)
```